# Max-height not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having problem to make `max-height: 100%` works in IE 10, (IE 9 too).

I found several Questions here in StackOverflow but none of them apply to my case. (A lot is dealing with fixed sized wrappers).

I'm showing an image in a modal dinamically.
I want to limit max-size to don't overflow visible window area.
So, I don't have any `height: xxxpx` because I don't want small images be stretched.
I won't also set wrapper div to `height: 100%` because I want that it adjusts to image size.

Here is a small demostration of the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<div id="thumbnail-container">
    <img src="http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sun_stereo_4dec2006_lrg.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#thumbnail-container img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andretf/8q634/)

It works in Chrome, but it does not work in IE. `max-width` works fine.

How can I make this work, without using Javascript?

Comment: Can't even view JSFiddle correctly in IE8 :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties like `min-height` and `max-height`, when used with percentages, are applying that percentage **as a percentage of the parent container**. Right now, you have no parent container, so that's a problem.

Additionally, if the parent container doesn't have height set to an explicit value, using `max-height` with a percentage will likewise not work.

So, to use `max-height: 100%;` somewhere, you must also have that element's parent container's height set to an explicit value (ie `50px`. Having a parent set to `50%` won't work, because 50% is not explicit; it's relative).

Comment: So, unfortunately, my alternative rest in Javascript?

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo That could be the case, yes, if you don't want to set heights in a parent container.

Answer (score 0):

max-height property works in IE7+, but only if the page has a standard DOCTYPE.
Try declaring the DOCTYPE of your document.
Try one of these:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also, if IE is in compatibility mode, that can cause problems. Try adding the following to your document `<head>`:

```
<!-- Forces user OUT of IE's compatibility mode and removes "broken page" icon --> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: I'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`